# Contour Plot of own coordinates with attached scalar

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the following coordinate system of (x,y) and attached z value to each coordinate. I need to keep the coordinates the same without using some linear fit function to change it into a grid system of some sort. Is there a way i can create a contour of that data using that data only and not using griddata or something.

```
x=[0.2,0.2,0.05,1.1,0.8,0.9,1.8,1.9,2.05];
y=[0,1.1,2.1,0.1,1.1,2.2,0.15,1.1,2.05];
z=[0,1,0,0,2,1,0,1,0;];

plot(x,y, 'bo')
```

The reason is i have another model with 540 thousand coordinate points that is a weird shape and if i start using the other functions it loses its shape and goes rectangular.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to use `fit`to create a fit surface of your data, and then directly plot it. This also has the advantage to give you extra parameters to control the interpolation between your points.

```
f=fit([x',y'],z','linearinterp')

plot(f,'Style','Contour')
```

Will create something like:

[image]

And

```
f=fit([x',y'],z','cubicinterp')

plot(f,'Style','Contour')
```

Will smooth the interpolation into:

[image]

Please look here for more information on `fit` and fit plotting options

https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html#inputarg_fitType

https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/plot.html

Comment: Thanks Noel, I wiil investigate this at work tomorrow